# Why can't I connect to my IP camera via RTSP?

Tags: ip, rtsp

I found this Forcovr Wifi IP Camera and want to stream its video via RTSP in the VLC app. The IP camera admin page reports it is transmitting data at ~800 bit rate, but I couldn't find any RTSP messages transmitted via Wireshark.
[image]

When I try to connect to the camera with a rtsp address using the device's IP (`192.168.1.208`) and assigned rtsp (`8554`) port I get an error in VLC logs along these lines:

`live555 error: Failed to connect with rtsp://192.168.1.208:8554`

`satip error: Failed to setup RTSP session`

I have tried variations of the address such as using the `rtp` protocol or adding login information and channel number to the url and even changing the port to the defaul 554,  but can't get the camera to connect. If the camera is sending data where is it being sent to? How can I find the rtp address to connect to if network analyzer fails to pick up any messages over this protocol?

Answer (score -1):

Run "ONVIF Device manager", https://demr.ru/rtsp-camera.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32309748)